# Why is my view model not binding and can't use foreach with mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Basically I get an MVC server model, serialize to JSON and pass this to javascript variable to bind to a table but nothing happens, I must be missing something.  Why doesn't this bind?

```
var categories = [{"Name":"BOOK","ID":"1"},{"Name":"MOVIE","ID":"2"},{"Name":"MUSIC","ID":"3"},{"Name":"VIDEO","ID":"4"}];

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(categories);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);


<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: viewModel">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can pass an array to ko.mapping.fromJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to this:

```
var data = {
    categories: [{"Name":"BOOK","ID":"1"},
                 {"Name":"MOVIE","ID":"2"},
                 {"Name":"MUSIC","ID":"3"},
                 {"Name":"VIDEO","ID":"4"}]
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: categories">
```

**[Test here](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/kjkm3/)**

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't bind either.

Comment: @zebula It does here: http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/kjkm3/ Maybe you have another issue

Comment: Yes, I see it does work.  I think I am confusing trying to bind viewModel and not the categories.